# No source jar attached with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have the following project maven (3.10) multi project:

```
my-mvn
 -> my-mvn-a
 -> my-mvn-b
 -> my-mvn-assembly
```

`my-mvn-a` and `my-mvn-b` build source jars using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-mvn</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-mvn-a</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In `my-mvn-assembly` I would like to build a zip including jars and source jars from `my-mvn-a` and `my-mvn-b`. The pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-mvn</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-mvn-assembly</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/resources/my_assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-mvn-a</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the descriptor:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>my-assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <includes>
                <include>my.group:my-mvn-a:jar:${project.version}</include>
                <include>my.group:my-mvn-a:jar:sources:${project.version}</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

but only the jar with the compiled classes is included in the zip. Why does it not include the sources jar build using the maven-sources-plugin?

Comment: Which version of the assembly plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest release: 2.4

Comment: Is this in an aggregator (with `<modules/>`?

Comment: Yes its an aggregator project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the phase in which you're generating the sources is too late. The `verify` phase comes after the `package` phase which means that your sources jar is getting generated, but it's well after the packaging of the assembly has occurred. Set the phase of the `maven-sources-plugin` to `package` and make sure the `maven-assembly-plugin` is defined in the same phase but declared after it (as Maven invokes the plugins in consecutive order).

**EDIT 1:**

I figured it out. You haven't defined a dependency to the sources artifact. Add the following and it will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-mvn-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You could further improve this by marking all your sources dependencies with scope `provided` and adding an invocation of the maven-dependency-plugin that executes the copy-dependency goal and copies them to a location under the target directory and then re-work your assembly descriptor to include those artifacts from there instead. This will make Maven not include the sources artifacts in wars/zips etc.

Comment: Yes adding it as a dependency was thing I was missing! Actually I am now using the maven-dependency instead in a similar way as you describe.

Comment: The way I described is the better way of doing it, as otherwise, if these dependencies aren't with provided scope, different plugins will include then in their operations and you clearly don't need the sources jars at those times. I would also like to recommend that you post more complete `pom.xml`-s in the future (such as the ones you added now) as this will help more people understand what your actual problem is. All the best! :)

Comment: So -- do I get the bounty? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input/help, I have assigned the bounty to your answer, leave a message if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you didn't include the version in the `<include>`.

According the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet), you can either use the short form:

```
<include>groupId:artifactId</include>
```

either the fully qualified form

```
<include>groupId:artifactId:type[:classifier]:version</include>
```

So try this:

```
<include>my.group:my-mvn-a:jar:sources:*</include>
```

or this

```
<include>my.group:my-mvn-a:jar:sources:1.0-SNAPHOT</include>
```

(using your actual version number of course, or better a property like `${my-mvn-a.version}`

Comment: Adding version has no effect, the zip archive still only contains the jar with the compiled classes.